# Not understanding extended class correctly

Tags: android

Bassicly my aim is too extend a activity so when the user presses Next how many times he wants to , i want to be able to display the value in the Activity2.
I want to somehow still keep the values stored into the variables even when i go into a new activity - im not too sure if thats possible. Any help would be appreciated

1st class

```
public class Activity extends Activity1 implements OnClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Next:

            if (value==0) {
              value=1;
            } 
              else if(value==1){
                  value=2
                 break;
}
               case R.id.one:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Form.class);
            startActivity(i1);
}
}
}
```

2nd Class

```
public class Activityv2 extends Activity1 implements OnClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            if(value==1){
display.setText("1");


}
else if(value==2)
{
display.setText("2");
}
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the value in a public [static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) field.

Edit: or you can save it in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), or pass this value through the activity using the [bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

For instance you can save it in this way:

```
  private void savePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

  private String loadPreferences(String key, String value){
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     return settings.getString("silentMode", "");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values between Activities and Fragment via a `Bundle` or an Extra in the Intent class.

To retrieve these back, in an Activity you would call getIntent() and either get the Extra out of this, or call getExtras() on the returned Intent to get the Bundle. In a Fragment you would call getArguments() which returns a Bundle.

Bundles are very handy, allowing you to pass primitive data easily between Activities.

Another option is to store these values in your own class which extends from `Application`, which you can then access anywhere and at any time.